# A question regarding triangle-free graphs

Tags: graph-theory

Given a simple triangle-free graph $G = (V,E)$, with $n = |V|$ and $m = |E|$. Show that 
$$\sum_{v \in V}d(v)^2 \leqslant mn, $$ where $d(v)$ denotes the degree of a vertex $v \in V$. I managed to prove the hint that for all edges $\{x,y\} \in E$, $d(x) + d(y) \leqslant n$, but I dont see how it relates to the inequality above.

Comment: Relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1635284/identity-for-sum-of-squares-of-vertex-degrees-in-graph

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that
$$\sum_{\{x,y\}\in E} (d(x)+d(y))=\sum_{x\in V}d(x)^2.$$

Comment: Wow nice one ! I missed this indentity.